# PostgreSQL - CREATE TABLE AS vs INSERT INTO performance comparision

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to insert couple of million rows into a PostgreSQL database. I am wondering what is the best way to do it.

1. CREATE TABLE AS
2. INSERT INTO

I'm looking to see which one is better and why? I have read through some blogs but still couldn't come to a conclusion.

I think INSERT INTO is a bulk insert operation. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Whether CREATE TABLE AS SELECT is a bulk insert operation?

Please advise.

Comment: You've not provided near enough information to be able to answer this question. There is not a single truth here, it depends greatly on what you are actually doing.

Comment: [Quote from the manual for CREATE TABLE AS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html): "*This command is functionally similar to SELECT INTO, but it is preferred since it is less likely to be confused with other uses of the SELECT INTO syntax. Furthermore, CREATE TABLE AS offers a superset of the functionality offered by SELECT INTO*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE AS` is a bulk insert operation as well.  The main difference is that `CREATE TABLE AS` is easier to optimize for PostgreSQL; it is clear that no WAL information has to be written (unless WAL-based replication is active, of course).  See the [`wal_level` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-SETTINGS) and [Disable WAL Archival and Streaming Replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/populate.html#POPULATE-PITR) for some other cases where this optimization applies.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When you say CREATE TABLE AS is easier to optimize for PostgreSQL, and no WAL information has to be written, INSERT INTO has to log everything to WAL? Have I understood right?

Comment: Correct. `INSERT INTO` has to log everything. I just checked PostgreSQL 9.4, and the optimization does not happen there for `INSERT INTO`, even if the table is created within the same transaction.

Comment: exactly what I needed to know. Thank you Florian